# Can using non primitive Integer/ Long datatypes too frequently in the application, hurt the performance?

Tags: java, performance

I am using `Long`/`Integer` data types very frequently in my application, to build Generic datatypes. I fear that using these wrapper objects instead of primitive data types may be harmful for performance since **each time it needs to create objects which is an expensive operation.** but also it seems that I have no other choice(when I have to use primtives with generics) rather than just using them.
However, still it would be great if you can suggest if there is anything I could do to make it better. or any way if I could just avoid it ??

Also What may be the downsides of this ?

Suggestions welcomed!

Comment: It doesn't matter until you can prove that it matters. Or at least show that it's very likely to matter soon (YAGNI is no excuse to use an O(n^3) algorithm for a component that will process huge n in production because your test data is tiny).

Comment: You're saying you have many collections with wrapped primitives. Have you tried [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com)? I never used it, but it might dispel your doubts.

Comment: it depends on your application.  In my case using primitives and **fast** collections like, say, Trove's *TIntLongHashMap* (instead of a *HashMap{Integer,Long}) definitely, totally and utterly **owns** the default Java API.  Constant needless wrapping and needless garbage creation means **much** more work than working with primitives.  There's a reason why amazing primitives collections like Trove exists: to answer your question, YES, using non primitive Integer/Long can hurt the performance.  Anybody saying otherwise has never tried Trove.

Comment: now does it matter in your application? It depends... For pet amount of data, it won't matter. But if your working with huge data, Trove saves the day...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repeat after me.  *"Creating an object in Java is not an expensive operation"*.

You are prematurely optimizing your application.  A better approach is to implement it in the natural way using `Integer` and `Long`, then profile it to determine where the bottlenecks are.  If the profiler tells you that use of `Integer` and `Long` is a performance issue, *then* look at ways to cure this.

---

If you determine that `Integer` and `Long` really are an issue, here are some things you could do:

- Look for a class library that implements "collections" of primitive types; e.g. Trove.  But beware that the APIs of such collection types *won't* be compatible with `java.util.Collection` and its descendants.
- Use `Integer.valueOf(int)` and `Long.valueOf(long)` rather than `new Integer(int)` and `new Long(long)`.  The `valueOf` methods use a cache of frequently used objects to reduce the number of object creations.

---

@Rex Kerr's comment is that this is horrible advice.  He is (I think) saying that the OP should optimize his application to reduce the use of `Integer` and `Long` before he *knows* that this will be a performance concern.  I disagree.

- At this point (when he asked the question), the OP didn't know that his application needed optimization.  If the application runs "fast enough" without any optimization, then any developer time spent optimizing it would be better spent on something else.
- At this point, the OP doesn't know *where* the performance bottlenecks are.  If they are not in the handling of these values, then optimizing this aspect will be a waste of time.  Note that generally speaking it is a bad idea to rely *solely* on your intuition to tell you where the bottlenecks are or are likely to be.
- @Rex Kerr posits that it would be a lot of work to modify/restructure the code to fix performance issues due to over-use of `Integer` and `Long`.  That's simply not true.  A decent IDE makes it easy to make this sort of change in a small to medium size application.

Comment: The lookup using valueOf might be even more expensive than new :) It would limit memory usage of course.

Comment: @extraneon: I'd be surprised if the Java team implemented `valueOf` such that it is slower than `new` (that would be a very stupid thing to do). The code looks up an eager instantiated immutable array of references using the exact index, so it seems likely that it would beat object instantiation.

Comment: @extraneon - in use-cases where the numbers are always big, `valueOf` will be marginally slower.  But you only need a small percentage of cache hits for `valueOf` to be better on average.

Comment: Creating an object in Java _is_ an expensive operation compared to most anything you would typically do with an int or long.  And your advice for something where it matters is horrible, because once you've implemented it the generic way and find that it's too slow, you pretty much have to _rip everything out and do it a different way with primitives_ (as you admit with your reference to Trove).  So this is only good advice in the case where the OP really doesn't need to worry about performance (which he probably doesn't, but a good answer is better when it covers the OP's concern).

Comment: @RexKerr - with respect to your last sentence, you seem to think that it is better to ignore the issue that the OP (and others who ask this kind of question) are *most likely* optimizing prematurely ... and help them waste their time.  I profoundly disagree with that.  A good answer is one that *helps* the questioner.  In this case, I'm using a bit of "theatrics" to make my point.  But it is obvious that's what I'm doing.  And anyway, that's my style.

Comment: @StephenC - Depends whether you think the OP knows what he is talking about.  If the program is, for example, to let the user select a bunch of files and output their paths in a list, then worrying about `int` vs. `Integer` is silly.  If the program is to analyze a 30 GB data file, storing things as `Integer` is stupid (unless you only will use the program once, at which point you must consider the entire time taken to write the program also).  "You can't know where bottlenecks are" is a myth when the bottleneck is a 20x+ slowdown.  But you have enough explanation now for me to remove the -1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many collections, or large collections, you are likely to have performance problems. See http://www.cs.virginia.edu/kim/publicity/pldi09tutorials/memory-efficient-java-tutorial.pdf.

If you have many collections, or large collections, or many large collections of boxed types (e.g. Integer, Long) there are alternatives: one is the Mahout Collections library, from http://mahout.apache.org. Mahout collections have open hash tables, which address many of the issues in the linked PDF, and collections that store little-i-integers, etc. Another is Trove, if GPL doesn't bother you.

If you are not sure that your code qualifies as 'many,' 'large', or 'many large', then by all means use a profiler and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Like others say,

> Premature optimization is root of
>   evil.

Having said that, [prefer primitive types to boxed types](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/general-programming/ch08lev1sec5) wherever you can.

UPDATE: Might also add that according to developers that work with high-performing code (like distributed cache) boxing can indeed become a performance problem quite frequently. I also worked with high-performing apps. but have never identified boxing as a worthy optimization place yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off profiling your application and looking at where your bottlenecks and hot spots are.  These are very hard to predict most of the time. IMHO  If you are not measuring, you are just guessing.

However, if you determine that using primitive in a collection would be more efficient, I suggest you try http://trove.starlight-systems.com/  It can make a big difference when it really matters but for 90% of the time, it doesn't.